# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView Android

Tags: android

I am able to test my android app on my mobile 5.0 perfectly fine, but testing it on anything lower than 5.0 throws an exception.

"Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView"

My line 16 is basically this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/main_app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I did see other posts about this error, but none of it seems to fix my issue.

This is the full callstack of the error

http://pastebin.com/raw/FaJQFCie

Comment: Post the whole layout file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. The error comes from navigation's menu. When I created new project with navigation drawer, Android Studio generates complete work for me. There's a drawable folder named drawable-v21 which stores the icon xml files

Answer (score 0):

I had had the same problem some time ago.

1) Look at your gradle dependencies: you should add library -

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

2) Look at your based colors: you should have

colorPrimary
colorPrimaryDark
colorAccent

3) Look at your layout.nav_header_main. If you will have in the end of error log some message like "Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to" - background image of nav_header_main has a very big resolution or kb weight. Change it and will have success ;)